# Is it possible to mix IAM authorization and an API key with AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, authorization

I've got an AWS Lambda function that I want to expose in two ways:

- to end users signed up to my webapp (using AWS Cognito User Pool)
- to external business customers, via an API key

I'm wondering if I can use an API Gateway with two different auth methods, potentially using different resources (=paths) for the two cases, with a schema like this:

```
API Gateway
|
| --- /getResponse
|     | --- Method: GET   // authorize with IAM
| --- /getResponseExternal
|     | --- Method: GET   // authorize with API Key
```

Is this possible at all? Or would I be better off just implementing two different API Gateways that both integrate the same Lambda function?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Each **resource** in API Gateway has two separate configurations: "Authorization" (via Lambda or Cognito) and "API Key Required"

You could ask for both in a single request, if you wanted to. My only suggestion to your layout would be to have two separate APIs, although this is not necessary, I find it easier to logically separate APIs by their end consumer (users vs business), but thats just my two cents!

[image: Resource Settings]